# button to generate html delete method?

Tags: python, html

I'm creating a little web app in flask using django and jinja2.  I have a python script running on some servers that generate html post requests, which then update a mongodb with some info.  These then show up on a dashboard.  Easy, i have that working.  However, i would like to include a button on the dashboard to remove them once i've addressed the issue for that server

in python i know I use

```
from flask import request
requests.post('http://<myserver>/api", data=some_event_data)
```

To remove the server I know in python i can use

```
from flask import request
requests.delete('http://<myserver>:5000/api", data=server_name)
```

to remove the server and drop it from the database.

...can i have an HTML button do the same thing?  I've tried a number of different things but the button always wants to submit and open http://:5000/api  but that's just an interface listening for data either with a post or delete method.

Any help would be great

Comment: `method="DELETE"` -- [see also](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.7)

Comment: i've tried method="delete" action="http://<myserver>:5000/api" but it attempts to open the page, and not just send the request.